# Error when using "parse_str" ... Undefined index: query

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the current page URL, which may look something like this:

> http://www.example.com/login.php/?redirect=myprofile.php

...and then get everything after the "redirect". Here is my code so far:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
//the complete URL is
$url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//parse URL and return an array containing the URL components
$url_components = parse_url($url);
//check to see if there is anything after the "?" by looking at "query" in the parsed URL
if (array_key_exists(parse_str($url_components['query'], $params), $url_components))
{
    echo "query exists in parse_str";
}
else { echo "query doesn't exist in parse_str"; }
```

However, I keep getting an error if the index `query` does not exists in the array:

> Notice: Undefined index: query

I've tried `isset`:

```
if (isset(parse_str($url_components['query'], $params)))
```

which gives me a HTTP ERROR 500 error when loading the page.

and `empty` gives me the same error as the first.

```
if (!empty(parse_str($url_components['query'], $params)))
```

I'm new to PHP, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what your tried for `isset`, and/or what `isempty` was? I would think `if(!empty($url_components['query'])) {`

Comment: if (isset(parse_str($url_components['query'], $params))) actually gives me a 500 error from the server and won't even load the page. I edited the post above to elaborate.

Comment: If `$url_components['query']` is not set, you can't call parse_str on it. Try `if (!empty(url_components['query'])) { parse_str($url_components['query'], $params); }`

Comment: That was it, thanks @drew010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to be checking the function call returns. You want to check that the `query` index exists. You can achieve that with:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/login.php/?redirect=myprofile.php';
$url_components = parse_url($url);
if (!empty($url_components['query'])){
    parse_str($url_components['query'], $params);
    print_r($params);
} else { 
    echo "query doesn't exist in parse_str";
}
```

`parse_str` can then be used when you have the `query` index.

https://3v4l.org/Vt3aa